# Retrieving report of users in Active Directory Security groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, report, powershell-4.0

I am trying to search a list of AD security groups and create a report of users in each security group. The report should have the Group Name, Name, UserName and UPN or Email Address.

I found some code that will help me with a majority of this. I need to modify it to display UPN or email address. Also I need to have it recursively search any groups. Currently the major issue I am tackling is displaying all of the information in the security membership object.

```
$Group = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\myusername\Documents\test\list.txt)

$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered] @{
"Group Name" = ""
"Name" = ""
"Username" = ""
}

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{

$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity -Group|selectname,samaccountname

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
{
$Record."Group Name" = $Group
$Record."Name" = $Member.name
$Record."Username" = $Member.samaccountname
$objRecord = New-Object psobject -Property $Record
$Table += $objrecord

}

}

$Table |export-csv "C:\users\myusername\Documents\securitygroups.csv"    -NoTypeInformation
```

The code is not pulling in all of the objects listed. For example a security group my have 3 users and 1 group listed as members. It looks as thought the script is only displaying the first 2 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Get-AdGroupMember` does not return userprincipalname or mail, you will need to get that data another way. One way is to call `Get-ADUser`.

```
$Record.UserPrincipalName = (Get-ADUser $Member).UserPrincipalName
```

You can make this slightly more efficient by replacing the `New-Object` command with the `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator. Also, you can just output the object in your foreach loop and assign that output to a variable. The way you are doing it (`+=`) forces PowerShell to expand the variable into memory before doing the reassignment. As the variable stores more and more data, that process becomes increasingly less efficient. The code below reflects the ideas I have mentioned.

```
$Groups = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\myusername\Documents\test\list.txt)

$Table = foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{

    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | select name,samaccountname

    $Output = foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
           "Group Name"       = $Group
           "Name"             = $Member.name
           "Username"         = $Member.samaccountname
           "UserPrincipalName" = (Get-ADUser $Member.samaccountname).UserPrincipalName
        }

    }
    $Output

}

$Table | export-csv "C:\users\myusername\Documents\securitygroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Ok. I ran the modified script and it returned, "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. ...argument is null. I had to replace variable after -Identity with $Groups

Comment: Receiving following error: `code`Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required 
by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:6 char:51
+     $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Groups | select name,samaccou ...
+                                                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: That is from your original code. What is inside of the text file?

Comment: it was just a basic text file in notepad no delimiters. Sorry tried to add it but formatting was off. I went ahead and edited the code again based off your example and looking up the error message. I will try to add my new code.

Comment: Followed info from another stackoverflow post to pull in list. \code $Groups = Import-csv -LiteralPath "C:\Users\user\Documents\test\list.csv" -Header "GroupName"

$Table = foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.GroupName | select name,samaccountname
    $Output = foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
           "Group Name"       = $Group.GroupName
           "Name"             = $Member.name
           "Username"         = $Member.samaccountname ,

Comment: \code          "UserPrincipalName" = (Get-ADUser$Member.samaccountname).UserPrincipalName
      }
    }
    $Output
}

$Table | export-csv "C:\users\user\Documents\securitygroups2.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Got it working now. The final code will work if the user you are running as has rights to view all groups in AD. In my case I did but I also had to "run as administrator". Is there a way to post the final code without touching the prior posts\comments? Thanks for your help @AdminOfThings.

Comment: You can just post an answer with the code that works.